# Oracle Insert Into NVarchar2(4000) does not allow 4000 characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, insert

I have a table with a field datatype of NVarchar2(4000)  I am moving data from a SQL Server to an Oracle Server.  The SQL Server datatype is also nvarchar(4000).  I have checked the MAX Size of this field on the SQL Server side, and the MAX is 3996, which is 4 characters short of the 4000 limit.

When I try to insert this data into Oracle, I get an error "LONG" due to the size.

What is going on here, will the Oracle NVarchar2(4000) not allow 4000 characters?  If not, what is the limit, or how can I get around this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a limit of 4000 bytes not 4000 characters. So NVARCHAR2(4000) with an AL16UTF16 national character set would occupy the maximum 4000 bytes.

From the [oracle docs of MAX_STRING SIZE](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/refrn10321.htm#REFRN10321):

> Tables with virtual columns will be updated with new data type
>   metadata for virtual columns of VARCHAR2(4000), 4000-byte NVARCHAR2,
>   or RAW(2000) type.

**Solution:-**

Also if you want to store 4000 characters then I would recommend you to use **[CLOB](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/CLOB)**

> A CLOB (Character Large Object) is an Oracle data type that can hold
>   up to 4 GB of data. CLOBs are handy for storing text.

You may try like this to change column data type to CLOB:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
 ADD (tmpcolumn  CLOB);

UPDATE table_name SET tmpcolumn =currentnvarcharcolumn;
COMMIT;

ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN currentnvarcharcolumn;

ALTER TABLE table_name
RENAME COLUMN tmpcolumn TO whatevernameyouwant;
```

Comment: I will implement this and see if it gets me past the issue..  Thanks

Answer (score 6):

First, as others have pointed out, unless you're using 12.1, both `varchar2` and `nvarchar2` data types are limited in SQL to 4000 bytes.  In PL/SQL, they're limited to 32767.  In 12.1, you can increase the SQL limit to 32767 using the [`MAX_STRING_SIZE` parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/refrn10321.htm#REFRN10321).

Second, unless you are working with a legacy database that uses a non-Unicode character set that cannot be upgraded to use a Unicode character set, you would want to avoid `nvarchar2` and `nchar` data types in Oracle.  In SQL Server, you use `nvarchar` when you want to store Unicode data.  In Oracle, the preference is to use `varchar2` in a database whose character set supports Unicode (generally `AL32UTF8`) when you want to store Unicode data.

If you store Unicode data in an Oracle `NVARCHAR2` column, the national character set will be used-- this is almost certainly `AL16UTF16` which means that every character requires at least 2 bytes of storage.  A `NVARCHAR2(4000)`, therefore, probably can't store more than 2000 characters.  If you use a `VARCHAR2` column, on the other hand, you can use a variable width Unicode character set (`AL32UTF8`) in which case English characters generally require just 1 byte, most European characters require 2 bytes, and most Asian characters require 3 bytes (this is, of course, just a generalization).  That is generally going to allow you to store substantially more data in a `VARCHAR2` column.

If you do need to store more than 4000 bytes of data and you're using Oracle 11.2 or later, you'd have to use a `LOB` data type (`CLOB` or `NCLOB`).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was running into..  I will look at using the NCLOB field..

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020) though the width refers to the number of characters there's still a 4,000 byte limit:

> Width specifications of character data type NVARCHAR2 refer to the number of characters. The maximum column size allowed is 4000 bytes.

You probably have 4 multi-byte characters.

Comment: Thanks for the info..  That is what it was..  I was looking at characters and not focusing on the bytes..